# Angular2 toggle menu from a child component

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-components

I have angular 2 application, with installed jquery and typings.

In my aboutPage component, I'm trying to apply jquery click event on button so that when the button is clicked, it suppose to add extra classes to navbar tag **outside** the about component using $(selector).addClass("some class");

But unfortunately it's not working. I've tried already to emit a call from child component and call a toggleMenu() function with jquery add class functions to add a class from the app component, but nothing is happening. Like jquery doesn't see the DOM

Edit1:
aboutPage Component:

```
$("header button.burger").click(function() { 
    this.commonService.notifyOther({option: 'onSubmit', value: 'From header'});
});
```

NavbarComponent:

```
private subscription: Subscription;

toggleMenu() {

jQuery("button.burger").addClass("active");
jQuery("nav").addClass("open");
jQuery("header").addClass("menu-open");

}
```

ngOnInit() {

```
// COMMON SERVICE COMMUNICATION
this.subscription = this.commonService.notifyObservable$.subscribe((res) => {
  if (res.hasOwnProperty('option') && res.option === 'onSubmit') {

    this.toggleMenu();
  }
});
}
```

Note: jQuery is working in app properly, except this part.

Comment: Forget about jQuery. Forget about modifying the DOM. Use Angular as it's meant to be used, and everything will be easier. Change the state of your components, and use their templates to add/remove CSS classes. Communicate between components using services.

Comment: Ok maybe it's not a good practices which I'm aware of but currently I need to solve it using jquery. Any real suggestions?

Comment: My crystal ball says the problem is at line 42. But it doesn't say which file, unfortunately. We can't fix your code without seeing it. I really don't see why you refuse to do things the easy and right way, and insist in doing it the ugly way, but hey, you're the one who will have problems, not me.

Comment: Is the emit value from child caught in the parent component correctly? Is the parent receiving the emitted value?

Comment: Yes parent received and toggle function also called properly, but jquery doesn't apply classes